# Turn an upstream struct into a trait

Tags: rust, traits

I've got to interact with some upstream code that exposes an interface that could be a trait but is instead implemented directly on a struct. I'd like to pull out that interface into a trait so that my code can support alternative implementations. This can in fact be done, but isn't particularly ergonomic:

```rust
pub mod upstream_code {
    pub struct Foo(());
    impl Foo {
        pub fn foo(&self) -> &'static str {
            "foo"
        }
    }
    impl Default for Foo {
        fn default() -> Self {
            Foo(())
        }
    }
}

mod my_code {
    pub trait Foo {
        fn foo(&self) -> &'static str;
    }
    impl Foo for super::upstream_code::Foo {
        fn foo(&self) -> &'static str {
            self.foo()
        }
    }

    pub fn do_something<T: Foo>(t: T) {
        println!("foo: {}", t.foo());
    }
}

fn main() {
    my_code::do_something(upstream_code::Foo::default());
}
```

Specifically, note that I have to regurgitate each function in wrapper form inside the `impl Foo for super::upstream_code::Foo` block.

There's Got To Be A Better Way! What's the most idiomatic way of handling this?

Comment: https://docs.rs/delegate/0.4.2/delegate/index.html

Comment: @Stargateur That's pretty handy, but not quite what I'm looking for. It still requires listing each method being delegated. It would be a lot nicer if I could delegate all methods in a trait at once...